# return what was not found in array in MongoDB

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, nosql

say my database collection has

```
* user collection*
[
{id:'1'}
{id:'2'}
]
```

I have an array of object

```
[
{id:'1'}
{id:'2'}
{id:'3'}
]
```

I want the object that was not found in the collection.

I want

```
[

{id:'3'}
]
```

I'm currently have this

```
 const records = await dbo
        .collection('user collection')
        .find({
          'id': { $in: newArr },
        })
        .toArray();
```

I'm a bit stumped on what to do! ... hope someone can help Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

**Option 1**:

Looks like this is what you need via the not in operation ( [$nin](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/nin/) ) when you need to check the not exisitng id in collection documents from provided array:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
 {
   $match: {
     id: {
      "$nin": [
         1,
         2
       ]
     }
   }
 },
 {
   $group: {
     _id: null,
     "idnotIntheArray": {
        $push: "$id"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Explained:

1. $match for any documents with id not in provided array.
2. $group all id's in an array

[plaground1](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Dy8hJ1ylLno)

---

**Option 2**:

And this is the option where you output only the array elements not existing in the collection:

```
  db.collection.aggregate([
 {
   $group: {
     _id: null,
     ids: {
       $push: "$id"
     }
   }
 },
 {
  $project: {
  missingFromCollection: {
    "$setDifference": [
      [
        1,
        5,
        4
       ],
        "$ids"
      ]
     }
    }
  }
 ])
```

Explained:

1. Push all id elements from collection to array ids ( note this solution will not allow more then 16MB total size of id's )
2. Use [$setDifference](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/setDifference/#mongodb-expression-exp.-setDifference) to identify the difference between the two arrays.

[playground2](https://mongoplayground.net/p/ae8_cpn5P6k)

Comment: Hi, I think you misunderstand the question, the user collection has records with id: 1, 2, while provided input array is with id: 1,2,3. Post owner wants to get the (object) value from the input array which is { id: 3 } (not exist in the collection). Just curious the possibility of this outcome =)

Comment: Thanks @Yong Shun ,  since it was not very clear from the question I have added the two options to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this aggregation:

```
db.entity.aggregate([
    {
        $match : {
            "myObjList.id" : 1
        }
    },
    {
        $unwind : "$myObjList"
    },
    {
       $match : {
            "myObjList.id" : 1
        } 
    }
])
```

and my aggregation result:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("6225a0f78d435fd2845f1dd1"),
    "myObjList" : {
        "id" : 1
    }
}
```